# Rails if object can't be found move on in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following statement in an erb template:

```
<% if @serial.hacks.find(@serial.id) %>
  <h1><%= @serial.hacks.find(@serial.id).hack_name %><h1> 
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to display the hack_name if it exists, however, prevent an error if it doesn't exist.  The Serial and Hack models share a has many through relationship.

When I load a page that doesn't have an association between Serial and Hack I get the following error which I'm trying to prevent:

```
Couldn't find Hack with id=2 [WHERE "hacktions"."serial_id" = 2]
```

Comment: Are you correctly searching for hacks where id = serial_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if hack = @serial.hacks.find_by_id(@serial.id) %>
  <h1><%= hack.hack_name %><h1> 
<% end %>
```

But you should use presenters.

BTW, it's ***really*** weird to have a `serial` having `hacks` with it's `id`. What do you really want?

---

Edit I guess you're looking for:

```
<% @serial.hacks.each do |hack| %>
  <h1><%= hack.hack_name %><h1> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I agree with @apneadiving, this code shouldn't be in the view.

Comment: @apneadiving What I want to display the field hack_name (located in the hack model), if a serial is associated with a hack.  If not it's skipped.  Your code is working, however, when I add a new Serial and associate it with hack, the hack_name is not showing up.

Comment: @apneadiving I now see my failed logic here :).  I have a hack (which can contain multiple serials).  When one clicks on the serial from a particular hack I want to show (in the serial view) which hack you came from (e.g. Return to hack_name). I guess I need to figure out whether I need a separate action in my Hack controller to 'show' serials that originate from hacks or whether I can use the default show action within the Serial model.